# Open-source song/music recognition on Android? (alternative to Shazam/Soundhound)

Tags: android, open-source, audio, music-recognition

I am looking for an open-source app that would do audio pattern recognition ([finger printing](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Fingerprinting)) on Android, in the style of [Shazam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android) or [Soundhound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melodis.midomiMusicIdentifier.freemium).

It should:

- recognize songs OTA (Over-The-Air), i.e. capture song by microphone and identify song
- be open-source
- work on Android

Comment: Not really a answer at all, and almost defiantly not open source :( but there is [Sound Search for Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ears&hl=en_GB) which at a guess checks against the contents of the Google Play Store for matches.

Comment: Untested: https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid (which makes use of the FLOSS music identification system [Echoprint](http://echoprint.me/), which also provides gratis song data)

Answer (score 3):

There is an app called "[Encore](http://www.encoremusic.io/)" which is a fully featured music player with a lyrics finder and music recognition. It's free and open source, Here are the links to [Github](https://github.com/fastbootmobile/encore), [GooglePlay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fastbootmobile.encore.app) and [the xda forums thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/encore-music/encore-music-to-experience-music-t3166515).

Possibly one of the app's downsides is that you can't launch quickly the recognition activity with a widget (last time I checked) - you have to enter the app and go there manually. Perhaps, you can [open an Issue](https://github.com/fastbootmobile/encore/issues/new) on Github with this feature request and you will have exactly what you need.